# Override a base localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, file, localizable.strings

Is there a way to have one base localizable.strings file for multiple targets within a project, and also have a second localizable.string file for each target that will override and append individual values to the base file?

**EDIT**

I want my app to have two .strings files - Localizable.string and Override.strings. If a string, Title.Welcome, is not found in OverrideLocalizable.strings then I would like the app to search Localizable.strings for Title.Welcome. Essentially, specifying Localizable as the fallback, but using OverrideLocalizable.strings by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
NSString *PSILocalizedString(NSString *key, NSString *comment)
{
    return NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key,
                                             @"OverrideLocalizable",
                                             [NSBundle mainBundle],
                                             NSLocalizedString(key, nil),
                                             comment);
}
```

What this will do is search a file called `OverrideLocalizable.strings` for the `key`. If the value for `key` is not found in `OverrideLocalizable.strings`, it will search `localizable.strings` for `key`. `NSLocalizedString(key, nil)` by default will search `localizable.strings`

Pretty simple and elegant solution

Comment: the iOS is not able to find the key in OverrideLocalizable and always returns value from main Localizable file. Do we have to place the override file in some specific place ?

Comment: Make sure the Override file belongs to the target you are specifying. I have an Override.strings for each target within the app and one Localizable.strings for all the targets have access to. If the string is not found in the Override.strings, it then goes and gets it from the Localizable.strings.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4 users that come across this issue...

```swift
func localizedString(
    for key: String, tableName: String = "OverrideLocalizable", 
    bundle: Bundle = .main, comment: String = ""
) -> String {
    let defaultValue = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: comment)
    return NSLocalizedString(
        key, tableName: tableName, bundle: bundle, 
        value: defaultValue, comment: comment
    )
}
```

Comment: Based on @tentmaking 's solution