# How to override a string in string localized file for a target

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I have a general localized file for all targets in my application. for a specific target I want to override an string value

general localized string file:

```
"string1" = "1"
"string2"= "2"
"string3" = "3"
"string4"= "4"
```

I want to set  "string4" to "four" just for one of targets.

```
NSLocalizedString(@"string4", nil)

---> for all targets except one: "4"
---> for that specific target: "four"
```

I don't want to write a condition and say read from general localize for all targets but for that specific target read from somewhere else.

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23066894/4468859

```
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"string4", @"OverrideLocalizable", [NSBundle mainBundle], NSLocalizedString(@"string4", nil), nil);
```

Is this way has performance problem or other problems or is it ok?